# Are $d^3r$, $d^3\vec{r}$, and $d^3{\bf r}$ the same as $dV$, the volume element?

Tags: notation, calculus, volume

I've seen the term $d^3r$, $d^3\vec{r}$, and $d^3{\bf r}$ being used instead of $dV$. Are they exactly the same? Do they have a different connotation?

Comment: Exactly the same thing.

Comment: As for connotation, the usual reason is that you have some function of $\vec{r}$ inside the integral, and maybe another of $\vec{r}'$, etc, and the first one helps keep a little better track over which variables are constant in the integration.

Comment: In my opinion, the first form connotes a "particular" type of volume - spherical, while the second form connotes a "general" type of volume.

Answer (score 4):

Writing $\int\ldots d^3r$ for an integral over volume is just wrong. The $r$ is written to look like a scalar, which doesn't make sense.

Writing $d^3\vec{r}$ or $d^3{\bf r}$ is the same thing. Writing a vector with an arrow or in boldface means exactly the same thing.

The difference between writing $dV$ and $d^3{\bf r}$ is simply that with the latter, you could use ${\bf r}$ in the integrand. For instance, $\int {\bf r}\cdot {\bf h}\;d^3{\bf r}$ makes sense and makes it clear what is going on, whereas $\int {\bf r}\cdot {\bf h}\;dV$ is weird-looking and doesn't really make it clear that the integration is over a varying ${\bf r}$. We can have integrals like

$$\int \frac{d^3{\bf r}_1d^3{\bf r}_2}{|{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2|}$$

for something like the energy of a uniform charge distribution.

Comment: +1 for having a clear example of an advantage for one notation over the other. I agree with the scalar $r$ point although would do that in handwriting a lot anyway as it's a fairly minor nitpick.

Comment: Come on, $d^dx$ is all over physics.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are the same.
But the first ones in terms of 'r' gives a better intuition of what variable we are varying.

Answer (score -1):

In order to perform in integration over a certain volume, you can write in a general way $$ \text{volume} =\int \text{d} V. \tag{1}$$
If you do your calculations in three-dimensional space, you can write this in an equivalent way: $$ \text{volume} =\int \text{d} V = \int \text{d}^3 r= \int \text{d}^3 \textbf r= \int \text{d}^3 \vec r, \tag{2}$$
where $\vec r$ and $\textbf r$ can be used to emphasize that $r$ has more components than one (although this is already covered by the "$\text d^3$" ($\to$ matter of personal taste).

The advantage of (2) over (1) is that you can distinguish between several variables. Let's look at an example: Say you want to integrate the function $f(\vec x,\vec y)$ over the volume. Something like  $$ ''\!\!\int\text dV\, f(\vec x,\vec y)\;'' \tag{3} $$
does not make too much sense. It would be better to clearly indicate which variable you want to integrate over, i.e. something like this: 
$$ \int\text d^3\vec y\; f(\vec x,\vec y) \tag{4}  $$

Comment: I've edited the second half of my answer